# Why is the closure of $[-1,0)=\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with Zariski topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Why is the closure of $[-1,0)= \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with Zariski topology?

Why $[-1,0]$ is not considered as a closure? It is closed and it contains $[-1,0)$.

Comment: Why not write down the definition of the Zariski topology, and then specialize to $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Yes, I did so, the finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself are closed in the Zariski topology. In that case, wouldn't [-1,0] be closed?

Comment: I think $[-1,0]$ is not a finite set, nor is it $\mathbb R$.  So it is not closed.